# How to use IUIAutomation::ElementFromIAccessible method in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, microsoft-ui-automation

I've tried to use `ElementFromIAccessible` method via:

```
 System.Windows.Automation;
 ...
 [DllImport("UIAutomationClient.dll")]
    public static extern int ElementFromIAccessible(
        IAccessible accessible,
        int childId,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref AutomationElement element);
```

where `AutomationElement` is from `System.Windows.Automation`.

And when I try to call it like:

```
 Win32.ElementFromIAccessible(this.Accessible, 0, ref automaitonElement);
```

It fails with

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException" "Unable to
>   pack parameter #3"

How Do I map it right way?

Comment: Why use the native libraries when Microsoft already provides a managed equivalent? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MickyD because there is no ElementFromIAccessible method in standard .Net library. I need to create AutomationElement from IAccessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL; DR;** essentially it's failing because you are trying to p-invoke a non-existent native method and also that you are trying to use p-invoke on a COM library.  COM does not (apart from `DllRegisterServer` and `DllRegisterServer`) list class methods in the DLL's export table anyway.  There is no such function called `ElementFromIAccessible()` in **UIAutomationClient.dll**.  However there is a interface member.

> How to use IUIAutomation::ElementFromIAccessible method in C#?

`IUIAutomation` and the like are COM types so you **should not** be using p-invoke.  Instead you should be using COM interop.

First, in your project add a COM reference to UIAutomationClient v1.0:

[image]

Then, using code like the following, you create an instance to `CUIAutomation` and invoke the [`IUIAutomation.ElementFromIAccessible()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671536(v=vs.85).aspx) method:

```
CUIAutomation automation = new CUIAutomation();
IAccessible accessible = // you need to supply a value here
int childId = 0; // you need to supply a value here
IUIAutomationElement element = automation.ElementFromIAccessible(accessible, childId);
```

> How Do I map it right way?

You can't cast [`IUIAutomationElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406(v=vs.85).aspx) to types in `System.Windows.Automation` because:

1. One is a COM type and the other is managed
2. [`IUIAutomationElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406(v=vs.85).aspx) is not defined in `System.Windows.Automation`
3. `System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement` does not realise `IUIAutomationElement` (the latter is a COM type anyway)

You should just use the COM UIA and refrain from mixing and matching.  Also, according to the doco, COM UIA has more features than the managed library.

### Dynamic

You could use .NET 4's features of dynamic COM object invokation using IDispatch like:

```
dynamic element = automation.ElementFromIAccessible (...);
string name = element.accName;
```

...however auto-complete won't work.  Since you already have access to UIA type library via the COM Reference which does provide strong typing, such an alternative is somewhat less useful.